# How do nickel alloys from power station switches work?

Tags: switches, power-electronics, arc, lightning, nickel

I have been told that switches made for 1000+ volts and amps use special nickel alloys that have higher resistance to wear and oxidation than pure nickel.
Where can I find the names and specifications of the alloys and how do they work on the atomic level?

Comment: Maybe start here and see if any of the references give you more useful info:  https://www.electrical-contacts-wiki.com/index.php?title=Table_of_Contents